# Get value from input in NodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I want to get value from a form:
Here's the form:

```
<form method='post' action='/stack'>
     <input name="stack0" value="stackoverflow0"/>
     <input name="stack1" value="stackoverflow1"/>
     <button type='submit'>Click</button>
</form>
```

if we want to get the value from the form we use:

```
app.post('/stack',function(req,res){
     var tmp = req.body.stack0;
     var tmp1 = req.body.stack1;

     console.log(tmp)  // stackoverflow0
     console.log(tmp1)  // stackoverflow1
});
```

I wont use this method because i have a lot of values, i want something like loop,

```
for(var i=0;i<2;i++){
    var tmp = req.body.stack(i); // any syntaxe like that ?

    console.log(tmp)  // souldstackoverflow0 if i==0,  souldstackoverflow1 if i==1
}
```

when `i` take 0; should `tmp` take req.body.stack0, and when `i==1` tmp = req.body.stack1 ? 
help plz, and thnx :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to use the bracket notation to access the object properties if you want to loop over them with a variable in the name:

```
for(var i=0;i<2;i++){
    var tmp = req.body['stack' + i];

    console.log(tmp) 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

We have to use BodyParser to grab data from the input field.
Code is here   HTML code

```
 <form class="" action="/" method="post">
 <input type="text" name="newItem" value="" placeholder="Please enter your task">
 <button type="submit" name="button">Add</button>
```

```
const express = require('express');
```

const bodyParser = require('body-parser')

const app = express();

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}));

var temp = req.body.newItem;
console.log(temp)